# How to update associated invoices when creating a payment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 application I have these two models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Attributes: date, amount, open_amount, etc.

  has_and_belongs_to_many :payments

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Attributes: date, amount, etc.

  has_and_belongs_to_many :invoices

  after_save :update_invoices

  ...

  private

  def update_invoices
    invoices.each do |invoice|
      new_open_amount = invoice.open_amount - amount
      invoice.update_column(:open_amount, new_open_amount)
    end
  end

end
```

Right now, creating a payment for a single invoice works and updates the invoice's `open_amount` as expected.

But what if one payment is used to update **two** (or more) invoices?

The payment `amount` should be distributed over all associated invoices, starting with the invoice that has the lowest `id` and ending with the invoice that has the highest `id`.

For example, if there are three invoices with an `amount` of `100` each, and a payment is created with an `amount` of `250`, then the invoice's `open_amount`s should turn out like this:

- Invoice 1:  0
- Invoice 2:  0
- Invoice 3: 50

How can this be achieved? I tried using a loop but failed due to my lack of Ruby skills.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def update_invoices
    remaining = amount
    invoices.sort_by{|i| i.id }.each do |invoice|
      tmp = invoice.open_amount
      next unless remaining > 0  #when the money is gone return
      new_open_amount = 0
      if remaining < invoice.open_amount
        new_open_amount = invoice.open_amount - remaining
      end
      remaining = remaining - tmp
      invoice.update_column(:open_amount, new_open_amount)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks a lot! When I apply your function to the use case above, though, the `open_amount`s of all three invoices gets set to zero. Still trying to figure out why that is...